# Heartbeat ubuntu server 12.04 is not assigning virtual ip?

Tags: server, nfs

I have two nfs servers and I have configured heartbeat on my both servers but when I started heartbeat it do not aign virtual ip to my servers

```
nfs-server-1 (eth0 172.16.203.20)
nfs-server-2 (eth0 172.16.203.21)
Virtual IP (172.16.203.23)
```

I configures **/etc/heartbeat/ha.cf** as follows on both servers same

```
logfacility local0 #used to tell heartbeat which log facility to utilize for logging 
keepalive 2 #interval between heartbeat packets currently every 2 secs you could also use 2000ms 
deadtime 5 # timeout before the other server takes over 
ping 172.16.203.20 #address to ping to determine if we are alive 
udpport 694 #port to listen in on for broadcasts made by heartbeat 
bcast eth0 #device to use for broadcasts 
baud 38400 #speed of serial device 
serial /dev/ttyS0 #serial device to use 
node nfs-server-1 # dns name of one of our two nodes 
node nfs-server-2 # dns name of other of our two nodes 
auto_failback on # very important or auto failover won't happen
```

And `/etc/heartbeat/haresources` as follows also same on both server

```
nfs-server-1  IPaddr::172.16.203.23/16/eth0 nfs-kernel-server
```

But when i test my servers ifconfig -a

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW 08:00:27:3d:a1:fb  
          Direc. inet:172.16.203.20  Difus.:172.16.255.255  Másc:255.255.0.0
          Dirección inet6: fe80::a00:27ff:fe3d:a1fb/64 Alcance:Enlace
          ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN FUNCIONANDO MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:18934 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:5581 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000 
          Bytes RX:3556847 (3.5 MB)  TX bytes:715714 (715.7 KB)

lo        Link encap:Bucle local  
          Direc. inet:127.0.0.1  Másc:255.0.0.0
          Dirección inet6: ::1/128 Alcance:Anfitrión
          ACTIVO BUCLE FUNCIONANDO  MTU:16436  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:54 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:54 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:0 
          Bytes RX:5304 (5.3 KB)  TX bytes:5304 (5.3 KB)
```

Whats wrong is with my configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well nobody answered me but At Last i found the solution,
I was putting the configuration files in wrong directory its not `/etc/heartbeat`

Its `/etc/ha.d`

So three important files should be copied there

```
/etc/ha.d/ha.c
/etc/ha.d/haresources
/etc/ha.d/authkeys
```

After doing this way my problem was solved!